# Improve the image quality after resize

Tags: image

I need to resize a large image using asp.net. But when i resize using bitmap property, its quality gets reduced. Is there any methods to improve the image quality? 
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

I used to enlarge my images with this tool : http://www.benvista.com/photozoompro

It offers many different algorithms and I was really satisfied with it.

Take a look if you can interact with a dll, it works most of the time. Ideally you should find a way to tell him to enlarge a file with a specific algorithm, then catch the new image on the server-side.

Comment: The results are awesome for me for graphics, resizing a .jpg two times larger. (I used S-spline-Max/Graphics Detailed Mode)

Answer (score 1):

I would use ImageMagick `convert` (or `mogrify`) in the following way:

```
convert input.png -resize 200% -filter Lanczos output.png
```

But for asp.net there is imageresizer: http://imageresizing.net/